How to remove $_GET timestamp from Magento AJAX Requests
Magento 2 adds a $_GET timestamp to every AJAX request URL to prevent browser caching. Since such requests or the result is PHP generated for me it doesn't make sense to prevent browser caching if the cache-control of such sources is no-cache. Also, the timestamp is not cache friendly if a page cache like LiteCache (LiteSpeed based page cache https://www.cachecrawler.com) is used. So my question is, how can this timestamp be removed in Magento?
